# How to Query pinned ParseObjects of different subclasses?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am trying to create a sort of a "Recently Viewed" feature on my app. The user class has a column of Array type where I store pointers to ParseObjects of **different subclasses.**

For example,

1. I have a ParseObject called Offers, I have another ParseObject of a 
   different subclass called Products.
2. The array in the user object class, called "RecentlyViewedItems", holds both of these types.
3. I fetch that array in the app and pin them locally.
4. I need to retrieve them from the pinned list, I usually retrieve items from
   pinned list using ParseQuery. But this particular pinned list contains
   ParseObjects of different Classes, and as far as I know ParseQuery
   only uses a specified subclass, and not a generalized ParseObject.

So, how do I retrieve items from a pinned list of different kinds of ParseObjects?

Answer (score 0):

Queries from pin are similar to queries from parse. Difference is only in setting property `query.fromPin();`
So, if your pin named as **"RecentlyViewedItems"**, your query should looks like this:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Offers");
query.fromPin("RecentlyViewedItems");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
        Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + scoreList.size() + " scores");
    } else {
        Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
});
```

[More info...](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#local-datastore-syncing-local-changes)